# При отправке Post запроса с помощью Swagger получаю пустой объект

Tags: spring-mvc, swaggerui

Отправляю Post запрос со страницы http://localhost:9003/swagger-ui.html

Вот тут получаю этот запрос отправленный с помощью Swagger-UI

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/book")
public class BookController {

    @PostMapping("/create")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Book postBook(@RequestBody Book book) {      
       log.info("Данные запроса {}", book );
       Book result = new Book(1, "bks", "aut");
       return result;
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения метода postBook получю пустой объект

```
Данные запроса Book(id=0, title=null, author=null)
```

Класс Book

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Book {

    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 0, max = 30)
    private String author;

}
```

Файл pom.xml с подключенными зависимостями Swagger и openapi

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>gw</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gw</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <postgres.version>42.2.19</postgres.version>
    <hibernate-core.version>5.6.2.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <jwt.version>3.13.0</jwt.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
    <openapi.version>1.6.2</openapi.version>
    <fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version>2.11.4</fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version>
    <swagger.core.version>2.1.10</swagger.core.version>
    <common.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!--    Swagger Core  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${openapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Вот что показывает консоль браузера (F12 -> network -> запрос -> payload)

```
{id: 0, title: "string", author: "string"}
author: "string"
id: 0
title: "string"
```

Comment: Что показывает консоль браузера (F12 -> network -> запрос -> payload)? Если отпрвлять не через swagger, а скажем через postman, запрос контроллер правильно отрабатывает? Для чего нужны `gson` и `jackson` в одном проекте, не конфликтуют эти зависимости между собой?

Comment: убрал gson из помника. Все равно получаю пустой объект. postman не могу проверить. На работе такое ПО запрещено. Но попробовал из VSC, результат тот же самый

Comment: Данные скорее всего правильно доходят. Метод контроллера возвращает строку а не объект, такого быть не должно для @RestController. Что отдает метод, 204 код и пустое тело?  Попробуйте удалить аннотации `@NotNull @Valid`, может без них отработает более правильно.  Как вариант добавить в метод параметр HttpServletRequest req и в дебагере посмотреть, приходят ли данные, есть ли они. Тогда смотреть на правильность конфигурирования спринг.  Ну и последняя догадка, добавить в Book  пустой конструктор и со всеми параметрами.